# Adding Taildwindcss into a Wordpress Custom theme - not working

Tags: php, wordpress, tailwind-css

I'm trying to create a custom Wordpress theme with Taildwindcss. Installed tailwind

tailwind.config.js

```
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  content: ["./*.php","./template-parts/*.php"],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

functions.php

```
<?php

function mytheme_register_styles() {
    wp_enqueue_style('mytheme-style-tailwind', get_template_directory_uri() . "/dist/output.css", array(), '1.0');
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'mytheme_register_styles');
?>
```

/src/input.css

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```

/dist/output.css

```
every class that taildwind generates.
```

style.css

```
the comment with details about theme. nothing else
```

front-page.php

```
<div class="bg-red-800">
    <h1>Hello sasa</h1>
</div>
<h3>heading3</h3>
<div class="border-y-green-800">
    <h2>hello</h2>
</div>
```

But the classes doesn't work..

i tried restarting localWordpress, adding / and removing from path. It doesn't seem that wordpress knows where to get that classes from.

sorry if it's something idiotic that i just missed out, but i just can't see it. Any solutions ?